# jQuery mobile elements not aligned center in div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a jquery mobile application.

I have a wrapper div that has css set to text-align: center. The problem is that the text input and checkbox elements are not getting aligned into the center of the login div.

I suppose I have to override the jquery mobile CSS but I do not know how to.

**CSS:**

```
.login {
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div class="login">
        <img id="logo" class="logoportrait" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        <br><br>
        <!-- Login -->  
        <label for="u"> gtt Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="u" id="u" value="">

        <label for="pw">Your Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" value="">      

        <label for="save" class="ck">Save My Login Information?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="save" id="save" class="ck">
        <br>
        <button>LOGIN AND TRACK!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks centered to me: http://jsfiddle.net/9wtqfptc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile provides a data-wrapper-class attribute for inputs which applies a CSS class to the wrapper DOM elements jQM creates when initializing its widgets.  Therefore you can apply a centering class with this attribute

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div class="login">
        <img id="logo" class="logoportrait" src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <!-- Login -->
        <label for="u">gtt Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="u" id="u" value="" data-wrapper-class="centerInput" />
        <label for="pw">Your Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" value="" data-wrapper-class="centerInput" />
        <br />
        <label for="save" class="ck">Save My Login Information?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="save" id="save" class="ck" data-wrapper-class="centerInput" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" data-wrapper-class="centerInput" value="LOGIN AND TRACK!" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.login {
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.centerInput {
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
label.ck {
    padding-right: 2.5em;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

I am also centering the text within the checkbox by equalizing the left and right padding and applying text-align.

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9wtqfptc/1/)**